# How to tell if there _are_ any working copy changes in git

Tags: git

I use `git diff --exit-code` to color my shell prompt so that I can see if there are diffs in the working copy. On very large repositories, this takes a very long time, as long as `git diff` without the extra argument.

I had hoped that `--exit-code` would cause git to exit as soon as it found the first difference, but in fact, it actually prints the diff. When run with `--quiet`, it of course doesn't print the diff, but still takes equally long, which suggests it's still computing all the changes, even if not showing them.

So my question is: is there a way with `git diff` (or any other git command) to simply check whether there *are* any diffs, and set an exit code accordingly, but without bothering to find and format all the actual changes?

**Edit:** For context on the size of the repo, it's about 7.5G (of which 4.1G is the `.git/` dir), and ~160k tracked files.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't any way to do this directly with git.

However, you can use the following shell script fragment to check much more quickly:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ `git status --porcelain=1 | wc -l` -ne 0 ] && exit 1
```

What this does is get machine parseable output from the `git status` command (which runs faster than `git diff` on large repositories because it is only checking for the presence of changes, not what they are), counting the number of lines (the `--porcelain=1` format will return exactly one line for each modified file, and no lines if none are modified), and then exiting with a non-zero exit status if the number is non-zero.

You could also just embed this directly in whatever script is generating your prompt by pulling out the conditional expression (the bit in the `[]`) and using that in whatever if statement is checking the exit code for `git diff --quiet` currently.

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately find a simple command, but I did check to see what the git prompt module in oh-my-zsh does, and it is reasonably fast:

Check the output of `git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no`.  When a file is modified, it will have an `M` in the second column, and when a file conflict is present, it will have a `U` in the first column.

You can do something like this:

```
prompt() {
    git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | grep '^.M' > /dev/null
    CHANGED=$?
    # $CHANGED -eq 0 when there are uncommitted changes

    git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | grep '^U.' > /dev/null
    CONFLICTS=$?
    # $CONFLICTS -eq 0 when there are merge or rebase conflicts

    git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | grep '^' > /dev/null
    CLEAN=$((1 - $?))
    # $CLEAN -eq 0 when there are *no* changes, conflicts, or uncommitted staged files
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to take about as long as the original `git diff` I posted above.